# View not showing edit options

Tags: 2010

We have recently upgraded to 2010. In one of the upgraded document libraries the default view does not seem to let many users have the right hand drop down menu for editing documents etc. I have rebuilt the default view 'All Documents' from scratch and made this the new default view but many users still have the same problem. Clicking onto another view and then back to the default view seems to make the edit menu reappear but obviously this is not very convenient. Any ideas what may be causing this?
Thanks

Comment: What browser are you using (IE, Firefox, Chrome)? Which version of the browser? Is this happening for all users, all of the time?

Comment: Hi Phil Sorry missed you had asked this question. We are using a combination of IE8, IE9 and IE10 and we have instances across each version. Still having problems grateful for any advice. Thanks David

Comment: Is the problem with only one document library? Have you tried comparing the traffic in Fiddler between a library that works and one that doesn't? If you have more log/diagnostic info please add it to your question and I'll dig in further.